# How to evaluate $\int \sin^{-1}(x)\cos^{-1}(x) \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I need to evaluate $$\int \sin^{-1}(x)\cos^{-1}(x) \, dx.$$ Can anyone please give me an idea or a hint ? Thanks.

Comment: it seems these are $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ functions. I suggest trying integrations by part. It works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we will use the fact that $\sin^{-1} x + \cos ^{-1} x = \pi/2$ and a change of variable $\sin^{-1} x = t, x = \sin t, dx = \cos t \, dt$ with these we get    $\begin{align}\int \sin^{-1}(x)\cos^{-1}(x) \, dx &=
 \int t(\pi/2 - t)\cos t \, dt \\
&=\int (\pi/2 t - t^2) \, d \cos t \\
&= (\pi/2 t - t^2)\cos t -  \int (\pi/2  - 2t)  \cos t\, dt \\
&=  (\pi/2 t - t^2)\cos t + (\pi/2  - 2t)  \sin t - 2 \int \sin t\, dt\\
&=  (\pi/2 t - t^2)\cos t + (\pi/2  - 2t)  \sin t + 2 \cos t +C\\\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer an answer that doesn't use trig identities, you can use integration by parts twice. You know the derivative of arcsin/arccos, and you can find the integral of the other through a table or another integration by parts. This will leave you with some function multiplied by another arccos or arcsin, depending on which you chose as your $dv$. You can then do another integration by parts using the trig function as your $u$ and the other function as your $dv$.